# Sharepoint REST API get item parent folder (if exists)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm looking for a way how to get list (document library) item with property on its parent folder, for that API call : `GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items({item_id})`. I know that I can specify $select but I don't know what property to pass (googling didn't provide any useful info).
Please advise
Thanks

Comment: What type of field are you trying to GET, is it a people and group lookup field?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround,you could try this rest:
`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileRef`

You can see the url of the parent folder.

Test result:
[image]

You could use jsom/csom/powershell to get item parent folder directly.

Comment: Thanks, Fileref is not exactly what I'm looking for, as it can change if parent moves. I',m looking for parent id (in Sharepoint Graph API there's such ID). But I can't find it in Sharepoint REST (V1)